# Doubt regarding Maximum Bipartite Matching

Tags: graphs

I was given this question by a friend:

"*You are given 3 sets of size n, X,Y and Z. Devise an algorithm to find maximum number of different pairings (u,v,w,x) such that u,v,w,x belong to X,Y,Z and X respectively (u is not equal to x) and gcd(u,v,w,x)>1.*"

My approach is to create new sets S and T, such that S contains pair (u,v) (create a node A) with gcd(u,v)>1 and T contains (w,x) with gcd(w,x)>1 (node B). If gcd(u,v,w,x)>1 add an edge between A and B. Now find maximum matching in this bipartite graph.

But he isn't satisfied and says I didn't use the gcd property and the problem can be reduced significantly. Can this algorithm be improved?

Comment: This problem is from ongoing programming contest.

Comment: What have you tried, to improve your algorithm?  What are your thoughts?  Are you familiar with the property that that $gcd(a,b,c) = \gcd(a,\gcd(b,c)) = \gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$?

Comment: what contest is it from? ref?

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/GNUM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible hint:

$$\gcd(u,v,w,x) = \gcd(\gcd(u,v),\gcd(w,x)).$$

I expect your problem can also be solved using the techniques in the following paper:

- Daniel J. Bernstein. [Factoring into coprimes in essentially linear time](http://cr.yp.to/papers.html#dcba). Journal of Algorithms 54 (2005), 1--30.

---

A maximal matching doesn't seem like the right approach.  The maximal matching algorithm you list will never choose two 4-tuples $(u,v,w,x),(u',v',w',x')$ such that $(u,v)=(u',v')$.  Thus, it won't produce the correct answer to the problem: it won't output the maximum number of different 4-tuples.